# Use a library installed in monorepo root in other packages

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, monorepo, lerna

I have a monorepo with a structure that is close to:

```
packages/
    client/
        src/
        package.json
    server/
        src/
        package.json
    shared/
        src/
        package.json
package.json
```

I want to install a package in the root folder, and use it in other packages.
To do this, I ran `npm i zod` in the root folder, then added `zod` as a `peerDependency` for all nested packages.

When I run `npm install`, I can see multiple instances of `zod` being installed across the monorepo. It exists on the root `node_modules`, but it also exists in other packages' `node_modules`.

I wouldn't bother this if `zod` didn't rely on having a single instance of it being installed. ([You have to check for `instanceof`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/blob/master/ERROR_HANDLING.md#a-demonstrative-example), and it won't work if the object was created in another package)

What's the best way of making sure I always use the same instance of an installed dependency?

---

I was thinking about using Lerna's `--hoist` option, or `useWorkspaces: true`, but both removed the `package-lock.json` from individual packages, and copied their contents with wrong dependency versions into the root `package-lock.json`. Seems a bit odd.

Comment: Were you able to find solution for this?